# Синоніми: Армреслінг - Рукоборство?

Tags: синоніми

Відповідно до цього офіційного і авторитетного джерела [Ukrainskamova](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/chinnij_pravopis/leksika/zastarili_slova_i_neologizmi/5-1-0-68), слова *Армреслінг* та *Рукоборство* вважаються синонімами, та не просто а навіть другий варіант наче замінив перший…

Я не зустрічала на просторах інтернету такі заміни. Чи ці слова дійсно є синонімами?

Нижче надаю посилання на перелік перевірених джерел в яких не знайшла такий синонім як “рукоборство”.

[https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=синоніми+онлайн&oq=синоніми&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60j69i59j0j69i61.2872j0j4&client=tablet-android-asus&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD&oq=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B8&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i60j69i59j0j69i61.2872j0j4&client=tablet-android-asus&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: за вашим посиланням не знайшов твердження, що *рукоборство* замінило *армреслінг*.

Comment: Друге посилання стверджує, що *«Приблизна кількість результатів: 57 000»*, і хтось може мати сумніви щодо того, що авторка у них усіх шукала і не знайшла. Мій мінус — саме за misleading statement. Ще поправив запрошення до субʼєктивних відповідей. І ще зауваження. Сайт ukrainskamova.com, який називає себе «офіційний сайт (?) української мови», зареєстрований на Росії, сервера знаходяться там же. Тому ним треба послуговуватися обережно. Якщо взагалі.

Comment: Перепрошую, але, як я зазначав уже [тут](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3376), так званий «Офіційний сайт Української мови» (ukrainskamova.com) не є ані офіційним, ані авторитетним. Це просто звичайний сайт, що обрав собі гучну назву. Авторитетними можна вважати сайти, за якими стоять представники НАНУ, відомі інститути або відомі мовознавці (а цей сайті навіть не оголошує своїх авторів чи приналежність). Що не виключає того, що на ньому може траплятися корисна інформація (але довіряти йому на 100% чи дозволяти дурити себе маркетинговими фокусами не варто).

Answer (score 1):

У Словнику української мови online (1-8) присутнє лише визначення

> **[АРМРЕСЛІНГ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=189898&page=72)**  Вид спортивної боротьби – змагання двох гравців з перетискування опертих на стіл рук.

Жодного підтвердження, того що словом ***"рукоборство"*** замінили вживання слова ***"армреслінг"***, я **не знайшла**.

Єдина стаття де ці слова вживаються, як взаємозамінні є в [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3), хоча аж ніяк не підтверджує того що ці слова повні синоніми.